# Python: BLPAPI Module Not Found

Tags: python, blpapi

I am trying to import blpapi (Python 3.8.2) but get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import blpapi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blpapi'
```

I set the environment variable: `BLPAPI_ROOT = C:\Program Files\Python\BLPAPI` and I made a copy of blpapi3_32.dll, blpapi3_32.lib, blpapi3_64.dll, blpapi3_64.lib in that file.

The C++ SDK is stored in `C:\Program Files\Python\BLPAPI\blpapi_cpp_3.12.3.1`

What else am I missing/do I need to do?

Comment: Have you looked at other similar questions? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+module+named+%27blpapi%27

Comment: Yes, most issues were resolved by setting the environment variable to the file path, but in my case that's not the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can manually copy the .dll files in C++API\lib (blpapi3_32.dll and blpapi3_64.dll in my case) into C:\windows\system32 where all the dll files that system uses.

Also, I copied the dll files in in C++API\lib into C:\blp\DAPI, replacing the new ones with the old ones.